# Dynamically change the id generator to "assigned" in NHibernate class mapping

Tags: nhibernate

I am doing some bulk inserts in a winforms application based on NHibernate. It would be of great help to me If I could dynamically change the ID generator type from "guid.comb" to "assigned" during program execution.

I came across James Kovacs' Weblog entry [Testing Immutable Entities with NHibernate](http://jameskovacs.com/2007/11/04/testing-immutable-entities-with-nhibernate/)

where he does a similar thing when he changes the class from immutable to mutable, but I just can't apply this to changing the generator type. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NHibernate - how to switch dynamically the generator for Id?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5089066/634872)

Comment: Hi Florian, in the post you're referring to, the solution is to switch to Fluent NHibernate. If anyhow possible, I'd like to avoid this (have to refactor all my mappings)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the answer to the question I linked to in my comment, you cannot change it after the SessionFactory has been created. Therefore, the only option you have is keeping a second instance of the SessionFactory (preferably also as a Singleton) around. That doesn't have to be created at the same time as the first. You can create it when needed, but since the creation is quite expensive, the recommendation is to create it once and keep it.

However, if you really only need it for a bulk insert that occurs only once or twice during the runtime of the application, then you could also get rid of it after the operation.

That was the theory, now to the practical part. The easy way would be having a copy of the Entity.hbm.xml file where you just change the generator attribute. For the creation of the SessionFactory you need to provide a parameter (maybe an Enum) so that you can decide which .hbm.xml files to use and which ones to ignore.

I suggest naming the default hbm file Entity.Default.hbm.xml and the modified one Entity.Special.hbm.xml. All the other hbm files can keep their names.

Here is a modifed version of the method I use to create the SessionFacory. (I put a bool as parameter here but in my code I use an Enum.)

```
private ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory(bool useSpecialHbmFiles)
{
    Configuration config = new Configuration();

    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "...");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "...");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "...");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, "...");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Isolation, "Serializable");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass, "...");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql, "true");
    config.SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Hbm2ddlKeyWords, "none");

    // filter hbm Files

    // Set reference to entity assembly
    System.Reflection.Assembly assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyEntity));

    // get Resource-files
    string[] resources = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

    // scan through all the hbm files and filter them according to the parameter
    foreach (string hbmFile in resources)
    {
        // This filtering here could probably be done simpler, but this is easy to understand
        bool addFile = false;
        // ignore any file that does not end with .hbm.xml
        if (hbmFile.EndsWith(".hbm.xml"))
        {
            if (hbmFile.ToLower().EndsWith(".default.hbm.xml"))
            {
                if (!useSpecialHbmFiles)
                {
                    // we want that file for this SessionFactory
                    addFile = true;
                }
            }
            else if (hbmFile.ToLower().EndsWith(".special.hbm.xml"))
            {
                if (useSpecialHbmFiles)
                {
                    // we want that file for this SessionFactory
                    addFile = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // neither default nor special -> we want that file no matter what
                addFile = true;
            }
            if (addFile)
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(hbmFile)))
                {
                    string resourceContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    config.AddXmlString(resourceContent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // create Sessionfactory with the files we filtered
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you only want to modify the generator class at runtime, you can modify the configuation before building the SessionFactory like this:

```
// get the mapping's Key property
NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue keyValue = 
    config.GetClassMapping(typeof(MyEntity)).Key as NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue;
if (keyValue != null)
{
    // set GeneratorStrategy (the same string you would put in generator class="..." in the hbm file)
    keyValue.IdentifierGeneratorStrategy = "assigned";
}
```

Now you can pass a parameter to your CreateSessionFactory() method and modify the configuration. You will still need a second SessionFactory. You cannot modify an existing one.

**Edit 2 (disabling Many-To-One):**

To disable a NOT-NULL property in the mapping for many-to-one properties, try the following:

```
NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass mapping = config.GetClassMapping(typeof(MyEntity));

foreach (NHibernate.Mapping.Property prop in mapping.PropertyIterator)
{
    if (prop.Value is NHibernate.Mapping.ManyToOne)
    {
        prop.IsOptional = true;
    }
}
```

Of course, this will only work if the foreign-key column in the DB allows NULL values.

Comment: Thanks Florian, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid: having to different hbm files for each entity. You should read up James Kovac's article I linked in my question. It surely seems possible to do it with 1 hbm file. He does this with the immutable property. I just can't figure out how to do it with the generator. The Config class has tons of properties and though I tried I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Željko Sorry, I thought it would just be one or two entities. I modified my answer with another solution.

Comment: Great Florian, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @FlorianLim Hi Florian, it's me again. Do you by any chance know how to disable the many-to-one mapping (foreign key) the same way. I could then run the import without the foreign keys and then run a sql script afterwards to enable the FKs. This would speed up the import up to 30% (have millions of rows to import from an DBF based system).

Comment: @Željko I hope I understood your request correctly. See Edit 2 in my answer if you want to disable the NOT NULL attribute in many-to-one properties. Of course the DB must allow NULL in those columns.

Comment: Florian, I need a slightly different approach. Maybe, I best explain the way I do the import to you shortly. When I do the batch import, I always use schemaexport to create a new import database from scratch. I have lots of complex tables which are very nice to load with nhibernate. These tables are small and fast to load. But for the big tables I use "BULK INSERT" instead. When I generate the primary keys in the small tables, I use the "assigned" generator, so I know the foreign key in the big tables. For faster performance, I'd like to disable the foreign key in the big tables on creation.

Comment: @Željko I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Do you actually want to prevent the creation of a foreign-key constraint in the DB? If yes, why? I have not done any performance tests, but if you fill that column with NULL first and update the column with the actual keys later, I don't think that will make much difference. Of course I could be wrong. I tried to solve this, and I was able to change the many-to-one side to a normal property but the DB still created a foreign-key contraint. Sorry. :)

Comment: Never mind, Florian. It' ok this way, too. I only asked because people on the internet were claiming that the import with foreign keys disabled would be faster up to 30%. I have no proof of this whatsoever.

Comment: @Florian Lim I just realized that when creating a SqlBulkCopy instance, you can specify a SqlBulkCopyOptions Enumeration as a input parameter. It has a CheckConstraints option which can turn on foreign keys (by default foreign key checks are turned off which I painly realized when trying to do a join on two related tables)